# Error populating Listview item using Entity Framework 4

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Hi i am trying to populate Listview from database using EF4. I tried to populate with the below code but nothing populate in the listview although items are fetching. Please help me how do i proceed.

```
 private void FillListView()
    {
        using (DiagnosoftDataContext context = new DiagnosoftDataContext())
        {
            var user = from c in context.Users
                          select new
                          {
                              Code = c.name,
                              Name = c.age,
                              Sex  = c.sex,
                              DOB =  c.dob,

                          };


            //Bind the ListView
            // Create items and subitems for each item.

            listView1.View = View.Details;
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem("lv", 0);

            var item = user.ToList();

            foreach (var u in item)
            {
                lv.SubItems.Add(item[0].Code);
                lv.SubItems.Add(item[0].Name);
                lv.SubItems.Add(item[0].Sex);
                lv.SubItems.Add(item[0].DOB);

            }

            // Create columns for the items and subitems. 

            listView1.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Age", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Sex", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("DOB", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not adding the created ListViewItem(s) to the ListView.

```
listView1.Items.Add(lv);
```

The creation of ListViewItem seems a little bit strange. In the `foreach` you are adding for each user 4 subitems with the values of first user of your enumeration.

I think that is not what you want and you want to add an item for each user with its values.

```
foreach (var user in item){
  ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(user.Name);

  lv.SubItems.Add(user.Code);
  lv.SubItems.Add(user.Name);
  lv.SubItems.Add(user.Sex);
  lv.SubItems.Add(user.DOB);

  listView1.Items.Add(lv);
}
```